# Running script through launchd with no annoying prompts

Tags: snow-leopard, applescript, launchd

I have an applescript that checks my macbook battery and forces hibernation when it reaches a certain level, after displaying a 60 sec countdown.

I've successfully set it up to run in the background via launchd, every 30 secs, as a script but this causes an annoying bouncing icon on the dock.

So, I saved the script as an app and now the dock icon is no longer bouncing but if I am in the terminal app (for example) and I happen to be pressing CONTROL just as it launches in the background, I get the dreaded "Press Run to run this script, or Quit to quit" dialog box. And yes I have made sure that when I save it the "Startup Screen" option is NOT selected.

[image: dialog]

This dialog appears behind all other windows so I have no idea that it has happened and my app/script is stuck at this point.

Any suggestions how to overcome this so I can run my script with no annoying dialogs or bouncing icons?

Thanks.

EDIT: One idea that came to mind was to use the ExitTimeOut option in the plist file. The man page says:

```
ExitTimeOut <integer>
    The amount of time launchd waits before sending a SIGKILL signal. The default value is 20 seconds. The
    value zero is interpreted as infinity.
```

So I added it in like this:

```
<key>ServiceDescription</key>
    <string>Battery Monitor</string>
<key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
<key>ExitTimeOut</key>
    <integer>90</integer>
```

then did unload/load of the .plist file. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to work. Am I understanding this option wrong?

Comment: Is your script confidential ? if not publish it so it can be reviewed.

Comment: not at all. Here it is http://pastebin.com/jNAfCyjg

Comment: Just tried the ExitTimeOut option. No luck. See EDIT for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Convert to Shell Script and AppleScript Pair

Convert your check for the battery status to a shell script. The shell script can then run regularly through a `launchd` job ticket without presenting any user interface.

When the conditions are met, your shell script can launch an AppleScript to interact with the user.

This assumes you use an `~/Library/LaunchAgent` approach for the launchd job ticket. A computer wide launchd job will not be able to launch the AppleScript component in the appropriate user session.

Alternatively, you could use a third party tool to [trigger on a battery event](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97492/event-based-on-battery-charge-level), such as [Power Manager](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2014-02-10-how-to-shut-down-before-battery-the-fails/index.html); this would avoid polling your battery and improve your battery's performance.

Comment: That is a good idea. I'll give it a try, thx. Are you sure polling the battery affects it's performance?

Comment: Running a script every 30 seconds will add load to your CPU and thus affect your battery performance. Ideally you want to hook into the battery system and wait for it to broadcast updates as events; search around "polling versus events" for more insights on this development topic.

Comment: Thx, I'll look into it. If anyone is interested in the bash version of the script it can be found here http://pastebin.com/1n3QvbEz. I'm accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Me bad. I just realised that the script is missing the line that checks the current % with the min. The corrected script can be found here: http://pastebin.com/QhcT3FGg