# What's a way to run an automator/bash/applescript command right when a laptop starts charging and right when it stops being charged?

Tags: applescript, automator, bash, automation

I'm trying to automate running a background application only when my laptop is charging to save battery.

So it will launch when I plug the laptop in, and quit when I take it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that very easily using [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com), a free (open-source) application:

> ControlPlane, a fork of MarcoPolo, brings context and location sensitive awareness to OS X. With ControlPlane you can intelligently reconfigure your Mac or perform any number of actions based on input from a wide variety of evidence sources [...]

*from: https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane*

You can very easily add a "power source rule" which then launches or quits an application or script. As you can see in the attached screenshots, it's very easy to set-up.

[image: Power source rule in ControlPlane]

[image]

Comment: looks like there's a trailing underscore in your github url

Comment: @user1757449 you're right, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

One option is a third party product like the one [discussed here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116528/55365) or the free [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/).

Another option is to write a script to query the status using `ioreg`. Here is snipset from code that I found elsewhere sometime ago...

```
set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -w0 -l | grep ExternalChargeCapable")
tell Cap to set {wallPower} to {last word of paragraph 1}
if wallPower = "Yes" then
    ....
end if
```

Have the script to run continuously so you can detect changes and then perform the action you desire as necessary.

Hope that helped.

Comment: interesting! i'm still curious if there's a way to execute something only when a macbook changes states from being plugged in/battery powered. thanks for the advice!

Comment: @user1757449 Did you take a look at the first link? The software is event driven. It doesn't poll. But costs $$. In any case, the above bit of applescript shouldn't be much of a drain on the system - if launched every few minutes...